# How to get Google's logo as a startup tile?

Tags: tiles, google

On a former phone I had this as my startup tile for Google (nice):
[image]

Incidentally, this appears to be an alternative (also nice):
[image]

But I'm stuck with this:
[image]

which is nothing other than the default pin-to-start cropped version available for any website and which is less elegant than the other two.

I know Google popped up with a custom "pin to start" option when I first loaded it on the new phone but I think I goofed it up. And since then I've never managed to get that option to reappear.

### Edit

The accepted solution no longer seems to work - the "pin to start" option doesn't appear even after deleting history.

Comment: I was looking for this myself, but I think Google removed this "pin to start" from their mobile web page.

Comment: I have a Google app (by Google Inc.) from the marketplace. Its pin to start icon looks like your second icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your IE settings and clear your history. Once done go back to google.com. Wait a second as the button is loaded after the page but you should see it. Tap the button, and pin the resulting screen.

Some people claim they had to reboot or refresh the page several times to get it to show up. I didn't need to, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Joe that worked. I've got a true blue tile now and no rebooting or refresh needed.

Answer (score 2):

That second alternative is not a pinned website, but an actual Google WP7 app. As far as I know it is still the only one, but you can find it here: http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=220bfbf2-ee02-496c-a656-651a6c0c6518

Comment: oh yes, i see. i'll remove that image since it's not what i'm after

Comment: That's the better solution than pinning up the google website. The app isn't that optimized like on android but it surely is a better way to have google search on your phone